# What are all the attacks you can perform with a Switch Axe?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

There's not really any kind of tutorial on how to use each particular weapon in the game, but I've been slowly figuring out some new moves with the Switch Axe over time as I keep playing.

A little while ago, I was able to perform a series of moves that I have not been able to repeat since. In axe mode, I was able to keep swinging the axe (using stamina each swing) horizontally one way then the other by repeatedly mashing the A button. Every time I've attempted since then, I do a single swing and then go into a long recovery animation.

How do I do that move? What other "hidden" moves or chains of moves exist for the Switch Axe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All weapon attacks are performed by using the A and X buttons with directional keys. The combo you're talking about is most likely what is called the "Alternating Slashes" combo. This is performed after an Upswing (Down + A) by hitting Up or Down.

Note that you cannot chain a side-step after this attack, leaving you somewhat vulnerable. If you have enough to time to perform multiple Alternating Slashes, it is probably more damage-efficient to use the charging thrust of the Sword Form.

A good guide for Switch Axe combos can be found [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/943655-monster-hunter-tri/faqs/59687).

Comment: I don't understand what this guide is telling me to do for specific moves. How can I press "up" while also "holding a movement direction"? If I press "left" or "right" or "down", my character will be facing utterly the wrong direction to do anything useful.

Comment: @StrixVaria Most of the attacks that require directional keys are chained from other attacks. There's a certain sweet spot in between attacks during which directional keys do not actually change your direction but can affect the next attack.

Answer (score 1):

On the DS version, if you press X and A along with the R button all at the same time, you perform a draw slash with it in sword mode. I found this pretty useful fighting nargacugas since they don't like staying in one spot for too long.